# select count() returns Exhausted Resultset

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I do a simple select count:

```
woCount = db.select("SELECT count(foo) as bar from baz");
retval = woCount.rs.getInt("bar");
```

The retval line throws Exhausted Resultset exception. How would that be possible? I mean, select count always returns exactly one row, so I cannot get an empty result. What am I missing?

Here is implementation of select method. Just for reference, it works perfectly fine in other places (SResultSet has no methods defined, only fields):

```
public static SResultSet select(String SQLQuery) throws DBException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    SResultSet crs = new SResultSet();
    try {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        while (conn.isClosed()) {
            conn = getConnection();

        }
        stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        //stmt.setFetchSize(fetchSize);

        crs.rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLQuery);
        crs.stmt = stmt;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        logger.error("DB : Select(String SQLLQuery) : Error=" + sqle + " SQL=" + SQLQuery, sqle);
        throw new DBException("Application error while executing database query", sqle);
    }
    return crs;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `rs.next()` even before the first row. A fresh `ResultSet` has a cursor placed before the first row. It needs to be advanced before anything can be read.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.next()` should be checked done before reading.